# Spread Syntax JSONB column in postgres

Tags: javascript, postgresql, jsonb, spread-syntax

How do I do the spread syntax in postgres UPDATE

`UPDATE TABLE <table_name> set data={...original, ...<new_data>} where id='<id>'`

in postgres

Answer (score 0):

where {"a": "b"} is the JSON object spreading into the current data

```
update <table_name> set data = data || '{"a":"b"}' where id='<id>'
```

when you need to change a nested value use jsonb_set

```
update <table_name> set data = jsonb_set(data,'{"a","b"}', '{"attr": "value"}', true) where id='<id>'
```

Comment: The `select` statement isn't necessary: `UPDATE t1 SET data = data || '{"a":"b"}' where id = 2`